# How to add Qt kits to Qt creator after installed?

Tags: qt-creator

I download the installer from the official site https://www.qt.io/download?hsCtaTracking=f24f249b-61fb-4dec-9869-50512342f8d9%7Cf3adf380-4740-4f7e-9e49-d06fa99445fa .
When installing Qt creator I skipped the Qt kit selecting step. Now I already installed Qt creator but cannot start any new project for Android because its kits selection step only contains a desktop option.

How to add Qt kits to Qt creator after installed? Or can only be solved by reinstall Qt creator? Please help.

Here is the installer view witch I skipped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the same setup and install more features.

Also in the directory where Qt was installed there exists a `Maintanance` executable. Just start that one and you will get the setup wizard and the chance to add the android kit.